# Comparing point patterns, each with differing windows

Tags: r, gis, spatial, spatstat

I am working on patterning statistics in R, using the spatstat package. I have a bunch of ppp objects, and would like to compare them all to find slight differences in the patterns of them that I might miss by just looking at the heatmaps, etc. I would also like to quantify the differences between the patterns somehow.

One problem is that the windows are differently shaped (slightly) for each pattern.

I am applying spatstat to plant leaves; here are the resulting tesselations to give you an idea of window shape, etc.:

[image]
[image]
[image]
            [Tesselation, Leaf 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TILJC.png)                           
[Tesselation, Leaf 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvCxS.png)                           
[Tesselation, Leaf 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0KSv.png)

How would I go about comparing the patterns, and seeing where they differ?
I would also like to see, for example, if after analyzing 10 patterns, there's commonly a band of increased density across the midsection of the leaf, that is hard to detect by simply looking at individual density images. Is there a way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas with two artificial datasets:

```r
library(spatstat)
set.seed(42)
W1 <- ellipse(1,2)
W2 <- rotate(W1, angle = pi/4)
P1 <- rpoispp(20, win = W1)
P2 <- rpoispp(20, win = W2)
plot(solist(P1=P1, P2=P2), main = "", equal.scales = TRUE)
```

[image]

Manually make a relevant center line for each window (you can use
`ends <- clickppp(2, add = TRUE)` on top of a plot of each individual pattern
to interactively choose the end points by clicking the plot and then use the
coordinates to create the line with `psp`):

```r
L1 <- psp(0, 1, 0, -1, window = W1)
L2 <- rotate(L1, angle = pi/4)
plot(solist(L1=L1, L2=L2), main = "", equal.scales = TRUE)
```

[image]

Define the distance from the center line:

```r
D1 <- distfun(L1)
D2 <- distfun(L2)
plot(solist(D1=D1, D2=D2), main = "", equal.scales = TRUE)
```

[image]

Then you can fit point process models with this covariate.
E.g. the simple log-linear model for one of the datasets:

```r
ppm(P1 ~ D1)
#> Nonstationary Poisson process
#> 
#> Log intensity:  ~D1
#> 
#> Fitted trend coefficients:
#> (Intercept)          D1 
#>   3.1368706  -0.1768286 
#> 
#>               Estimate      S.E.    CI95.lo   CI95.hi Ztest       Zval
#> (Intercept)  3.1368706 0.1912389  2.7620491 3.5116920   *** 16.4028872
#> D1          -0.1768286 0.3328005 -0.8291056 0.4754484       -0.5313351
```

Where the log-linear effect of distance to the center is insignificant as
expected (since the data was generated with homogeneous intensity).
From here you can explore different types of models (e.g. proportional to
distance via `offset()`, Gibbs models, models for replicated experiments via
`mppm()`, which may be very relevant here, etc.). E.g. a joint log-linear
model for the two datasets:

```r
dat <- hyperframe(points = list(P1, P2), linedist = list(D1, D2))
mppm(points ~ linedist, data = dat)
#> Point process model fitted to 2 point patterns
#> Call: mppm(points ~ linedist, data = dat)
#> Log trend formula: ~linedist
#> Fitted trend coefficients:
#> (Intercept)    linedist 
#>  2.98511651  0.06387864 
#> 
#> Interaction for all patterns:    Poisson process
```

Chapters 9 (freely available online), 13 and 16 in the
[spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org)
may be useful (**disclaimer:** I’m a co-author).

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at that material and try it out with my data. Do you happen to know of any way to construct a model taking into account parameters such as distance from window edge of each point, distance from a line horizontally bisecting the leaf at the center, point density, and nearest neighbor? Would those all be covariates in the model? Apologies for the questions, I'm new to this type of modelling!

Comment: Yes, distance to window edge (`distfun(W1, invert=TRUE)`) and distance to horizontal line (analogous to the center line) are covariates you can use in the same way. However anything involving the points themselves is not a covariate. You can introduce dependence among points by using e.g. Gibbs interaction in the call to `ppm()`.